# Download file in Struts 2 using annotation

Tags: struts2, annotations, download

I would like to ask if anyone can help me with an example to download a file using Struts 2 annotation

I have tried this in my action class

```
public class MyClass {
private InputStream       fileInputStream;

    private String      fileName;

    @Override
    @Action(AbstractBasisAction.VIEW)
    public String view() {
    System.out.println("HoursCycleDownloadFrameAction: view");
    super.view();
    return SUCCESS;
    }

    public InputStream getFileInputStream() {
    return fileInputStream;
    }

    @Action(value = "downloadFile", results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "stream", params = { "contentType", "application/octet-stream", "inputName", "fileInputStream", "contentDisposition", "filename=\"${fileName}\"", "bufferSize", "1024" }) })
    public String downloadFile() throws Exception {
    fileName = "license.txt";
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\", fileName));
    return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

and this is what my page contains

```
<s:url id="fileInputStream" namespace="/myClass" action="downloadFile" ></s:url>

Download file - <s:a href="%{fileInputStream}">lisence.txt</s:a>
```

but the problem now is that it downloads the file with the action method name. Means that the file name is downloadFile.action. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: To "download" a file ? What do you mean ? What have you tried ?

Comment: I have edited the post so you can see what I have tried

Answer (score 0):

1) if it is a .txt file, `"contentType", "application/octet-stream"` 
should instead be `"contentType", "plain/text"`;

2) you need a getter for your `private String fileName;` variable;

3) `"contentDisposition", "filename=\"${fileName}\""` should contains extension, and eventually `inline` (default, open in browser) or `attachment` (ask if donwload or open with client application), for example

`"contentDisposition", "attachment; filename=\"${fileName}.txt\""`